# encode String into a URL in browsina java

Tags: java, url

how can I convert a String into a Url. some thing like following example. i want to encode `https://abc.com/msds/AFALON MSDS.pdf` into `https://abc.com/msds/AFALON%20MSDS.pdf`.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html):

When encoding a String, the following rules apply:

1. The alphanumeric characters "a" through "z", "A" through "Z" and "0" through "9" 
   remain the same.
2. The special characters ".", "-", "*", and "_" remain the same.
3. The space character " " is converted into a plus sign "+".
4. All other characters are unsafe and are first converted into one or more bytes using some encoding scheme. Then each byte is represented by the 3-character string "%xy", where xy is the two-digit hexadecimal representation of the byte. The recommended encoding scheme to use is UTF-8. However, for compatibility reasons, if an encoding is not specified, then the default encoding of the platform is used.

try like this

```
System.out.println(URLEncoder.encode(
         "https://abc.com/msds/AFALON MSDS.pdf", "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20"));
```

Comment: 'replace("+", "%20"))' part makes the change. it replaces the '+' marks into '%20' and creates a working url. although 'encode' creates a url consists of "+" it does not working. anyway thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html and call the encode() method

Comment: this gave 'https://abc.com/msds/AFALON+FLOWABLE_16103696.pdf' as output although i want 'https://abc.com/msds/AFALON%20MSDS.pdf'